# How to perform in-app purchase with hardware and services on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a react native app and within the app (iOS and Android), would like to provide in-app purchase. I'm selling hardware as well as subscription services associated with hardware. What do I need to do to support in-app purchase in this scenario? Do I need to enable iOS app entitlement for in-app purchase Or can I just link to our web page inside our app and redirect user to webpage to order hardware and buy services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use out of the box api of in-app purchase for android and ios. But you can only use these for subscription and selling digital goods, **no physical articles**.

For selling physical goods as Amazon does, you must implement your own logic (server), you can use PayPal or masterpass api for incorporate secure payment method in your app for example. I recommend services like amazon web service or firebase for provisioning your server (backend).

In case of android visit this page [in-app purchase for android](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html)

In case of ios visit this page [in-app purchase for ios](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html)

Hope helps

Comment: Thanks Worldken, My followup question is, what if i do the following, will it make Apple or Google unhappy Or will they reject the app? I am planning to do simple solution
1. My website already have solution to sale the hardware and services. I just want to redirect the user within the app to our web page to buy the hardware and services. 

Will this solution have any problem with Apple or Google?

Comment: If you use android or apple api for selling physical products, Google and Apple have all the permission and right to suspend your app. And yes, you can redirect users from your app into the web page where selling logic is already implemented for allowing them to purchase articles, there is no problem with that.